# Protractor e2e testing

Tags: protractor

I am writing Protractor e2e testing .I need to Dynamically read the values from Excel .Can anyone help me out from this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read/write from/to an excel using NodeJS - Protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616522/how-to-read-write-from-to-an-excel-using-nodejs-protractor)

Comment: Also do take a look at [xlsjs npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsjs). It works well too.

Answer (score 0):

**Inititally add xlsjs to node, and then try this code**

```
var sheetNumber = 0;
    //Define file Path name
    var path = require('path');
    var fileNamePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'E:/excel.xls');
    //NodeJs read file
    var XLS;
    if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
        XLS = require('E:/node/node_modules/xlsjs');
    }
    //Working with workbook
    var workbook = XLS.readFile(fileNamePath);
    var sheetNamelist = workbook.SheetNames;
    var value = workbook.Sheets[sheetNamelist[sheetNumber]][cellId].v;
```

*In the above sheet number means, in the Excel sheet your data is located in which sheet and cellId is in that sheet which shell data do you want. your data was stored in the variable value, you can use that data in any type.*

Comment: From this i could read the values. But i want to save the same value in "Grid"(ag-grid).. i could locate the cell value in grid. How should i send the value which is read from excel??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know like that.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Its working for me.But if my excel has no value in any of the column, getting error like "undefined" . How should i address that

Comment: do you want to send it to search field in grid?

Comment: as normal sendkeys, select locator then send keys into search field

Comment: Yes.. i did like that only.. But when excel has values , it accepting . If some of the column of excel does not have value mean,It showing error like 'undefined' is not a function...

Comment: Do i need to check any condition if excel has no value??

Comment: write a condition, if not equal to null run the logic, otherwise go to next column value,